# How can I add screensavers?

Tags: screensaver

I guess some of the screensavers in Ubuntu are nice. But I'd really like more. Is there a website with screensavers for Ubuntu?

Also, I am particularly looking for a screensaver that looks a bit like Mac's ribbon ribbons of light thing.

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
sudo apt-get install xscreensaver-gl-extra
```

There's a nice once called Flurry but it's quite intensive on the computer and not a very energy-efficient method of **not** using your computer.

Here's what it looks like:

[image]

Edit. There's a whole load more in `xscreensaver-data-extra` too if you want something different.

Comment: Curious to know who and why somebody gave this a -1. If you vote against something, you should explain why so the person has the opportunity to improve their post.

Answer (score 6):

#### Electric Sheep

I'd recommend Electric Sheep. Electric sheep automatically downloads various sheep and you can upvote the ones you like. More popular sheep are displayed more often and vice versa. For more information see [electricsheep.org](https://electricsheep.org/).

[image]

Comment: Didn't work. Black screen.

Comment: What does running the command `electricsheep` in the terminal produce? Also run `electricsheep-preferences` and test your connection. You may have to wait for some sheep to be downloaded first.

Comment: electricsheep connects to the net; it'll work but it first downloads the files, which takes time. Also worth noting that it does use a good bit of bandwidth, so other people on your network/downloads you do will be drained by this screensaver...it's worth it, though. Hypnotising...

Comment: Takes too much time, I give up. But I agree it looks fantastic.

Comment: For recent releases, check this new installation guildeline: http://www.distrogeeks.com/install-latest-electricsheep-ubuntu/

Answer (score 2):

You may also look at the Ubuntu Software Center for the GLX Screensavers, those are a port of the famous Really Slick Screensavers for Windows and Mac.

Those screensavers have the look and feel of great Mac/Windows screensavers.